# how to redirect user to a new view controller after successful Facebook login in iOS app under Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

i am very new to this. i have made an iOS app and did fb integration in it using api key and secret.in my app i have 3 view controller. in my first view controller i have login button ,in second view controller i have my app front page and in third controller i have my app info page.what i want is on pressing login button and after successful authentication,control should go back to my second view controller rather than coming back on first view controller having login button.here below is my code:
                                    **appdelegate.m**
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import 
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FBLoginView class];
           // Override point for customization after application launch.
    sleep(2);
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
}
@end

                               **viewcontroller.m(my firstviewcontroller)**

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    //[loginView setFrame:CGRectMake(55, 343, 210, 50)];
    // loginView.center = self.view.center;
    //[self.view addSubview:loginView];
    if (![FBSession.activeSession isOpen])
    {
        // presentLoginViewController
        return;
    }


    else
    {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 //self.label.text = user.name;
                 //self.userProfileImage.profileID = [user objectForKey:@"id"];

              //   NSLog(@"FB id : %@",appContext.userName);


                 //Present your view controller after logged in
                // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"authentication" sender:self];
                 UIViewController *ViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"<name of xib>" bundle:nil];
                 [self presentModalViewController:ViewController animated:YES];
                 //[ViewController release];

             }
         }];


    }
}



//- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
//{
   // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"authentication" sender:self];

//}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    //  ViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: r u using xib in storyboard

Comment: You can call your second view controller after the login authentication